# Travel insurance that covers a laptop

Tags: uk, europe, insurance

I'm about to head out on a trip via train to see a friend. I was planning on taking just the bare essentials (change of clothes and a sleeping bag), but said friend has requested I bring my gaming laptop.

Now, the laptop is heavy, which is why I'd be inclined not to bring it in the first place, but it's also new and expensive enough to make me worry. I wouldn't want to bring it without insuring it.

Fortunately (ish?) I hadn't gotten around to getting travel insurance yet (I know you're supposed to do it straight away but there we are). So I can explore looking into insruance that would specifically cover my laptop. But I quickly found not everywhere has an option, and there's this "business trip" catagory that some seem to squirrel the option away under.

Can anyone help me make sense of what's best to do here?

I'm travelling from the UK to the low-countries and staying for a few days. I could potentially be doing this trip a couple of times over over the comming year. I may also be moving there (I don't think travel insurance covers moving costs but I could be wrong).

Comment: Check your Home & Contents policy if you have one. There's often an 'all risks' section that covers items like cameras and laptops away from home. Travel insurance policies also generally cover items up to some specified value, without explicitly saying it's a laptop. Failing that, call one of the specialist travel insurance companies in the UK and tell them what you want covered and they'll add it to a policy as a special item.

Comment: I think you understand the issue. "What's best to do," however, depends upon your assessment of the risk, your willingness to shoulder that risk, and the cost (buying insurance, or not taking the laptop) of ameliorating the risk. All are matters of opinion, and of your personal feelings about how much risk and how much cost are tolerable or desirable for you.

Comment: I was basic travel insurance for *whatever is normally recommended for travel insurance*, but I also want to make sure that my +£1k laptop is covered, which seems to fall afoul of many £250 single item limits. Business trip options don't seem to be what I'm after but I'm having difficulty confirming that.

Comment: What do you mean by *low-countries*? Netherlands?

Comment: @BernhardDöbler In the UK 'the Low Countries' is generally taken to mean The Netherlands, Belgium and Luxembourg.